# save checked checkbox php

Tags: php, checkbox

I need your help please to get something working.

I've a kind of a link parser which put the links in an array and displays them with a checkbox at the beggining of every link.
I've separated all the work into multiple files :

- Form.php which contains only the HTML form.
- Confing.php contains the necessary lines to connect to database.
- New.php contains the source
  and checkbox.php to save checked links in database.

Now, what I want is to be able to save only checked links in the database, but instead it saves everything.

Here's the code (in New.php) to add a checkbox to every link of the array :

```
// $r is the array

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($r);$i++)
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='recup[]' value='".$r[$i]."'>".$r[$i]."<br>";
}
$_SESSION[sup] =
```

At the end of this file, an action to start checkbox.php :

```
<form action="checkbox.php" method="post"> 
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'>
```

The file chekbox.php :

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit")
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($r);$i++) 
        {
            $query="INSERT INTO ub0oi_newcraw_liens(id,url,description) VALUE(NULL,'$r[$i]','Lien')"; 
            mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
            echo "Record is inserted.";
        }
    }
?>
```

I Only want to save the checked value, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not catch checkbox `post` value:

try this code:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
    { 
       $r=$_POST['recup'];   // you forget to add this line 
        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($r);$i++) 
        {
            $query="INSERT INTO ub0oi_newcraw_liens(id,url,description) VALUE(NULL,'$r[$i]','Lien')"; 
            mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
            echo "Record is inserted.";
        }
    }
?>
```